# Is there any reason to do all these pull-ups?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After finishing the main storyline of the Citadel DLC, you get the option to invite certain crewmembers up to your apartment for a scene.  When you invite James in, he notices your exercise equipment as he's leaving.  At this point, you can interact with the pull-up bar and he'll challenge you to beat his record - 182 pull-ups.

You can indeed manually do these pull-ups one-by-one.  Is there any point or reward to completing this?

Comment: I think this question is more suited for http://fitness.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I actually did them all.  There is no material reward or achievement that I could discern for finishing - James was pretty impressed with me, though, so there might be dialogue impacts somewhere down the line.  I might note that I did this before throwing the party and he didn't mention it at any point.

(For the record, even though it uses paragon/renegade prompts to step you through the motions, your reputation scores do not change.  Also it took probably at least 15 minutes...)

Comment: The comments James makes are varied as well. Did the pull-ups on different playthroughs and sometimes he had more commentary, sometimes less.

Comment: All his comments are pretty lackluster, too.  (Well, okay, him trying to get me to give him a high-five at least made me chuckle momentarily.)

Comment: it's hard to chuckle when you've been hitting renegade and paragon interrupts for the last 5 minutes...

Answer (score 13):

Beating James' record has no effect at all, it's mainly for unlocking the conversations that occur while doing the pull ups (which are nothing all that ground breaking). Replaying it multiple times (why would you do that) only includes minor variations on the conversations that occur while doing the pull ups.

Completing the challenge will have no effect on any conversations outside of that meet up, and doesn't provide any kind of achievement (other than knowing you beat James).

While you are using the Paragon and Renegade triggers to do the pull ups, you're not actually changing your Paragon/Renegade levels at all by performing the pull ups.

I had read somewhere that inviting each member of your team up before the party would result in the contents of the party changing but that also didn't appear to be the case (I invited *everybody* up and nothing changed in comparison to my previous parties).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that most of the DLC is nods to various jokes about the games within the community, I think it's meant as a reference to the infinite paragon/renegade glitch in ME1.

If you don't know, the short version is that early in the game you can exploit an oversight in the structure of a conversation to choose the paragon and renegade option over and over as much as you want, until you've maxed out both meters if you choose to. If you want the details there's plenty of guides on how to do it.